# Java Memory Limit -Xmx suffix: upper vs lower case m/M and g/G

Tags: java, memory, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

It is commonly known that it is possible to limit the Java heap size with `-Xmx<amount><unit>`, where `unit` is the data amount unit like Gigabyte, Megabyte, etc.
I know that `-Xmx128M` means 128 Mebibytes (= 128 * 1024 * 1024 bytes).

But is it true, that it is also possible to use decimal units like megabytes using `-Xmx100m`
(which would be 100 * 1000 * 1000 bytes)?

So is it possible to use this decimal units by using lower-case unit suffixes like `k, m, g` instead of `K, M, G`?

Comment: BTW The case generally matters, it's just that javac doesn't care.  Note: there is no need to wonder whether g/G means 100^3 or 1024^3 because it won't be exactly either. ;) On my system running `System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());` with `-Xmx1g` prints `954728448`

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's interesting to know.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no difference between k and K both means `kibibyte` and so does m/M = `mebibyte` & g/G = `gibibyte`. you can set `100m` as the value and it will be `100 * 1024 * 1024 bytes`. generally it is advised to use this value in `powers of 2.`

Hope it helps.

Comment: *why* is it advisable to use in powers of two ? I would question that. If you want to add 1g to an 8g server, that should be no issue.

Comment: Until a few years ago it was a popular convention, in my opinion there is no advantage in using powers of two

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just try `-Xmx100m` and `-Xmx100M` and check if there is any difference.
`k, m, g` work exactly like `K, M, G` - they all mean binary units.

Answer (score 2):

All memory sizes used by the JVM command line arguments are specified in binary units (Kibibyte, Mebibyte, etc.) regardless of unit capitalization; where a 'kilobyte' is 1024 bytes, and the others are increasing powers of 1024.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32858015/1850308) goes into a more complete technical answer to the question.