# Does java -Xmx1G mean 10^9 or 2^30 bytes?

Tags: java, units-of-measurement

And in general, are the units used for the `-Xmx`, `-Xms` and `-Xmn` options ("k", "M" and "G", or the less standard possibilities "K", "m" or "g") [Binary prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) multiples (i.e. powers of 1024), or are they powers of 1000?

The manuals say they represent kilobytes (kB), megabytes (MB) and gigabytes (GB), suggesting they are powers of 1000 as defined in the original [SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) system.  My informal tests (that I'm not very confident about) suggest they are really [kibibytes (kiB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte), [mebibytes (MiB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) and [gibibytes (GiB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte), all powers of 1024.

So which is right?  E.g. what Java code would show the current size?

Using multiples of 1024 is not surprising for RAM sizes, since RAM is typically physically laid out by doubling up hardware modules.  But using units in a clear and standard way is ever more important as we get to bigger and bigger powers, since the potential for confusion grows.  The unit "t" is also accepted by my JVM, and 1 TiB is 10% bigger than 1 TB.

Note: if these really are binary multiples, I suggest updating the documentation and user interfaces to be very clear about that, with examples like "**Append the letter k or K to indicate kibibytes (1024 bytes), or m or M to indicate mebibytes (1048576 bytes)**".  That is the approach taken, e.g., in Ubuntu: [UnitsPolicy - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy).

Note: for more on what the options are used for, see e.g. [java - What are the Xms and Xmx parameters when starting JVMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Mainly I'm asking the question, looking for a definitive answer.  The documentation suggestion is just intended to add more clarity on what I'm confused by.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Short answer: All memory sizes used by the JVM command line arguments are specified in the traditional binary units, where a kilobyte is 1024 bytes, and the others are increasing powers of 1024.

Long answer:

[This documentation page on the command line arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) says the following applies to all the arguments accepting memory sizes:

> For example, to set the size to 8 GB, you can specify either `8g`, `8192m`, `8388608k`, or `8589934592` as the argument.

For `-Xmx`, it gives these specific examples:

> The following examples show how to set the maximum allowed size of allocated memory to 80 MB using various units:
>
> `-Xmx83886080`
>   `-Xmx81920k`
>   `-Xmx80m`

Before I thought to check the documentation (I assumed you already had?), I checked the source of HotSpot and found the memory values are parsed in [src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/7209073ce7da/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l574) by the function `atomull` (which seems to stand for "ASCII to memory, unsigned long long"):

```cpp
// Parses a memory size specification string.
static bool atomull(const char *s, julong* result) {
  julong n = 0;
  int args_read = sscanf(s, JULONG_FORMAT, &n);
  if (args_read != 1) {
    return false;
  }
  while (*s != '\0' && isdigit(*s)) {
    s++;
  }
  // 4705540: illegal if more characters are found after the first non-digit
  if (strlen(s) > 1) {
    return false;
  }
  switch (*s) {
    case 'T': case 't':
      *result = n * G * K;
      // Check for overflow.
      if (*result/((julong)G * K) != n) return false;
      return true;
    case 'G': case 'g':
      *result = n * G;
      if (*result/G != n) return false;
      return true;
    case 'M': case 'm':
      *result = n * M;
      if (*result/M != n) return false;
      return true;
    case 'K': case 'k':
      *result = n * K;
      if (*result/K != n) return false;
      return true;
    case '\0':
      *result = n;
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}
```

Those constants `K`, `M`, `G` are defined in [src/share/vm/utilities/globalDefinitions.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/7209073ce7da/src/share/vm/utilities/globalDefinitions.hpp#l196):

```cpp
const size_t K                  = 1024;
const size_t M                  = K*K;
const size_t G                  = M*K;
```

All this confirms the documentation, except that support for the `T` suffix for terabytes was apparently added later and is not documented at all.

It is not mandatory to use a unit multiplier, so if you want *one billion bytes* you can write `-Xmx1000000000`. If you do use a multiplier, they're binary, so `-Xmx1G` means 2<sup>30</sup> bytes, or one stick o' RAM.

<sub>(Which is not really surprising, because Java predates the IEC's attempt to retroactively redefine existing words. Confusion could have been saved if the IEC had merely advised disambiguating the memory units with the qualifiers "binary" and "decimal" the occasional times their meaning wasn't clear. E.g., *binary gigabytes* (GB<sub>2</sub>) = 1024<sup>3</sup> bytes, and *decimal gigabytes* (GB<sub>10</sub>) = 1000<sup>3</sup> bytes. But no, they redefined the words everyone was already using, inevitably exploding confusion, and leaving us stuck with these clown terms "gibibyte", "tebibyte" and the rest. Oh God spare us.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for finding the code!  Very clear.
But I must note that it is the computer folks who redefined previously unambiguous terms that were over two centuries old.  For the IEC to keep them as they had been used for so long, and provide new terms for new units, makes all kinds of sense to me.  MiB is much less cumbersome, and much more easily formatted, translated etc, than "binary megabyte" or "MB_2".

Comment: Thanks for finding that documentation.  It has much clearer examples to clarify their use of MB and GB than the documentation I had found on my system (Ubuntu) and in my web searches.  Looks like they clarified it, perhaps for Java 8 :)

Comment: For Oracle Java 8 the situation is strange. Setting `-Xmx8g` ends up in a `maxMemory` of 7.11 GiB (7635730432 bytes)... With Java 11 I am getting the full 8GiB.

Answer (score 6):

You have two options to get answer for your question:

a) inspect source code of JDK. Sorry I was unable to google it in 5 minutes.

b) write a simulation, run it several times and make some observations.

```
public class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("total: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
  }
}
```

And run it several times:

```
java -Xms130m -Xmx2G A
total: 131072000
java -Xms131m -Xmx2G A
total: 132644864
java -Xms132m -Xmx2G A
total: 132644864
java -Xms133m -Xmx2G A
total: 134742016
java -Xms134m -Xmx2G A
total: 134742016
```

So educated guess is that java uses not an exact number, but 2^n approximation of the number you requested.

Answer (score 1):

In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701207/why-do-xmx-and-runtime-maxmemory-not-agree) concerning the `-Xmx` flag, `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` is used to show the current size. It is also noted that `-Xmx1024m` and `-Xmx1g` result in identical output, indicating that the numbers are powers of two rather than ten.

Note the difference between `totalMemory()` and `maxMemory()` as well.
[What are Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() and freeMemory()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571203/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-runtime-getruntime-totalmemory-and-freememory)

Comment: The question you reference is spot on!  Check out in particular [class MemTest by Alex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23702224/507544) there, for a full accounting of non-heap memory (including Code Cache, and Perm gen pools) vs heap memory (including Eden Space, Survivor space and Tenured gen pools)