# JVM committed heap memory is more than Xmx

Tags: java, heap-memory, java-heap

I have these jvm param set

```
-Xms24g -Xmx24g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=17 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=75 -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags
```

But In my heap statistics it shows [image: heap stats]. How can committed be more than Xmx?

Comment: [GB vs. GiB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855984/does-java-xmx1g-mean-109-or-230-bytes) `24*(1<<30) = 25769803776`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in jconsole it shows values in GB

```
GB to GiB

Multiply by (1000³ / 1024³), equivalent to 0.931323

Divide by this value to go from GiB to GB
```

25.8*0.931323 = 24.0281334